# webform mail error. messages coming up with sender's details blank

Tags: php

The messages I am receiving from my web form coming up without any sender's details.  I am a beginner. Could someone guide me to get it to work. Here is the screenshot of the error and the php and js.

[image]

```
<?php

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $status = array(

        'type'=>'success',`enter code here`

        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));

    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));

    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));

    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));


    $email_from = $email;

    $email_to = 'myname@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' 
. $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;


  $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');


 echo json_encode($status);

die;
?>
```

---

Validation

```
$('.contact-form').submit(function () {'use strict',

$this = $(this);

$.post("sendemail.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(),function(result){

if(result.type == 'success'){

$this.prev().text(result.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

}

});

return false;

});
```

Comment: Do a var_dump on $POST, remove the error suppression `@` and post the form in your question.

Comment: Sorry. I know nothing about PHP.